# magento 2 How to get dropdown selected value in knockout js on button click

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, knockoutjs, checkout-page

I have my custom payment method on the checkout page with the dropdown list.
and I want to get that dropdown selected value in knockout js and forward it to the controller and store the dropdown value in my custom table.

/view/frontend/web/template/payment/custom.html

```
      <div class="field field-number required">
                <label for="credit_days" class="label">
                    <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Click & Collect Credit Days'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                    <select id="credit_days"
                            class="credit_days"
                           name="credit_days"
                           data-validate="{required:true}"
            onChange="if(this.value=='requestmore'){document.getElementById('request_more').style.display='block';}else{document.getElementById('request_more').style.display='none';}"
                           data-bind="value:creditDaysSelected(), optionsCaption:'Please chose days...'"
                           >
                        <option value="10days">10 Days</option>
                        <option value="20days">20 Days</option>
                        <option value="30days">30 Days</option>
                        <option value="40days">40 Days</option>
                        <option value="requestmore">Request More Days</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div id="request_more" class="request_more" style="display: none">
                    <label for="request_more_credit_days" class="label">
                        <span></span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="control" id="require_more">
                        <input type="text" data-validate="{required:true}" name="request_more_credit_days" id="request_more_credit_days" placeholder="Enter credit Days of your choice" required>
                        <button type="submit" class="button primary action"> <span translate="'Submit Request'"/> </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want to store dropdown selected values to my custom DB table at the click of a button using a controller.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check function  selectPaymentMethod()

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/default.js
```

and then you can get the selected payment using

```
var paymentMethod = quote.paymentMethod();
```

Comment: I already getting selected payment method but i want  selected value from dropdown which are associated with my custom selected payment method

Answer (score 0):

**Replace your Select Field with This Code**

```
data-bind="value:creditDaysSelected, optionsCaption:'Please chose days...'"
```

**And Get Value Using This Code**

```
this.creditDaysSelected = ko.observable();
```

Comment: bro using value:creditDaysSelected i am getting already selected credit days. not the options value. and one more thing i don't have any idea about knockout js. It is totally new thing for me. so please give me detailed solution.